# ExtJS5 ViewModel using global declared store

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs5

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001134/extjs-5-grid-store-viewmodel-binding-cannot-modify-ext-empty-store) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100087/extjs-chained-store-to-globalstore-in-viewmodel), there are 2 ways of using an external declared store into a viewModel. In the first example `type` is used and in the second one `source` is used.
My Problem is that `type` and `source` are not [documented](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) as config part.

Is there any other way to use external declared stores in a viewModel? Which one should be used? Why? Where is the related documentation to find?
(I use extjs5.1.1 GPL)

Comment: The `type` property is supported because the `store` has the `Factoryable` mixin.
`source` is a required property for chained stores: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.ChainedStore-cfg-source

Comment: As for where that's documented - in the stores property of the View Model, there is a brief mention that "This store uses store chaining to create a store backed by the data in another store." Not the most "in-your-face" documentation, but it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` should be used if you want to create a new instance of a Store, per view model.

`source` should be used if you have a store instance (either passed in, or available globally through the store manager) that you want to use as the backing store. As a chained store, data changes will be passed through, but you can sort or filter it without impacting the source store (which is handy for displays).

You can also create or assign stores directly. Assigning (e.g assigning a store passed into the view) is fine, but creation is discouraged - if you use `Ext.create` to create a new store when defining a ViewModel, that store will be on the prototype, and shared amongst all the ViewModel instances. In general, you'd be better off using the StoreManger than doing that.